# Weighted least squares estimator

Tags: beta-regression

I have this linear model:

=  + ,  = 1, … , n

with variance proportional to the covariate, like $(_) = 0 $ and $() = ^2_{}$.

I need the weighted least squares estimator of beta.

I'm not really sure how to proceed, so far I've thought maybe to relate beta to $$\frac{s_{xy}}{s_{xx}}$$ but then I have no idea how it relates to the rest of the problem, I'm in way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've arranged your data in vector format: $\bf{y}=\beta\bf{X} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, where $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{X}$ are $n$-dimensional. (I'm assuming from your notation that $\beta$ is scalar, but the formulas below are the same for the multivariate case).

Ordinary Least Squares:
$\hat{\beta} = ({\bf X^TX})^{-1}{\bf X^T y}$

In weighted least-squares:
$\hat{\beta}_W = ({\bf X^TWX})^{-1}{\bf X^T Wy}$,

where ${\bf W}=diag(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ is $n\times n$ and diagonal. If you look at $\bf{W}$ as a means to favor low noise samples, you'd want to use it to suppress high variance samples. In that case a good choice for the diagonal elements of $\bf{W}$ would be to use values proportional to the inverse of $Var(\epsilon_i)$. In the extreme case, for example, sample $j$ with infinite noise variance (i.e., $Var(\epsilon_j)=\infty$) will be ignored, since its corresponding $w_j=0$.